# How can I create images like this one?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, maps

Does anyone here know how I can create tileable images like this one:

[image]

Can I use photoshop? any good tutorial?

I am a novice when it comes to design.

Comment: Do you need to be able to **create** these images?  Doing a google search for free cloud backgrounds ought to turn up a bunch of pre-made images and then just put them into Photoshop and use an adjustment layer to change the color to whatever color you need.

Comment: Yes, because I'm going to render good looking clouds and these images represent cloud density.

Comment: In that case, I would google "creating a cloud background in Photoshop." There are a TON of tutorials and you will probably need to try the techniques in more than one before you can create an image that achieves what you are looking for.

Comment: I hesitate to recommend any specific tutorial because ideally you want to find one that demonstrates using your specific version of Photoshop (in my experience, it can be super frustrating to follow a tutorial when Adobe has made changes to the toolbars or functionality in the version of the program you are using).  Plus, it will depend on your comfort level with the program--I know you say you are a design novice, but you could still have been using Photoshop for years to retouch photos, for example.  I would just try a few and see which tutorial works best for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an ordinary black and white image clouds or a desaturated color image. This clouds, for example, is an inverted to a negative. I suggest you to invert it back and you can see:

[image]

Quite dark! Probably the negative was adjusted a little brighter. The photo is an ordinary one only technically. There seems to be two different kinds of clouds at different altitudes.

Nearly every photo editing program should have these capabilities (=desaturate, invert, adjust brightness and contrast), no need to get any "high cost" or "complex to use" software for this. But if you want to start from scratch, not from a photo, then the abilities of Photoshop or other complex software are welcome.

Comment: Thank you! After a few Google searches("storm clouds background"), I found this: http://hisplace.nuulab.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/23/2016/02/bigstock-Dark-Storm-Clouds-Background-66048286.jpg https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/81/3e/9e/813e9e742114c2dbfcc68aaeaa05e63a.jpg

Comment: @karl Both of your new foundings are negatives. of cloud images. Maybe it's a cliche' to change the  soft roundness to a turbulentness by inverting the BW image.    BTW: You told you're a beginner. Before you get into troubles take a look at "what is legal - when can I use the photos which are not my own ". You should learn what copyright and licensing mean and stick with them, if you are going to sell something or to distribute something as free or to keep something generally visible.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes, I need to find free images for commercial use. Images of storm clouds that can be split into smaller parts, rotate them, merge them, blend them and convert the whole new image to grayscale.

Answer (score 3):

To Achieve that Just consider that You need 2 main steps:

A) - Create a image with the desired effect.
B) - Make this image tileable.

To make a desired effect you can use many different ways... you can make a research to marble texture on the net or achieve that using the clouds filter + another filters mixed. So lets do it...

1 - Create a new square file in Photoshop (500x500px) it can be any size.

2 - Go to Filter/Render/Clouds, using this filter it will create a clouds effect that is similar to what you are looking for.

3 - Now try to apply another filter to improve the results to match better what you are looking for.

4 - When you complete the effect, now It is time to make it tileable.

5 - Go to Filter/Other/Offset (before may be necessary to merge layers, if your image are using more than one layer)

6 - After the OFFSET filter applied, just edit the borders edge to make it with smooth transitions.

7 - If you do a good edition, you will be able to apply the same OFFSET filter many times without seen any border, meaning the image is perfect tileable.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So these days there are tile plugins etc, but the way to do this manually is, at its most basic:

Take an image.

Make a selection that is exactly 1/2 the width and 1/2 the height, copy it, and then paste it into a new layer or doucment such that it is in the opposite quadrant of the image (if it is the upper left, paste it lower right, etc).

You now have an image where the old outer edges (the parts that will meet in a tile) are at the center, and every new outer edge is already seamlessly matched to the other edges.

You now focus on the "inner cross" where the four quarters meet, using clone tools etc to try an make that cross disappear.

You can then use it as-is, or re-rearrange the quadrants back to the original configuration. If you do rearrange them again, you can touch up anything at the center.

Comment: Note photoshop has an **offset tool** that will do the re-arrangement.